# AngularFire2 RC5, Ionic, Map results from observable

Tags: observable, ionic3, angularfire2

I have my application working correctly when accessing the Angularfire modules directly on my pages.  However, I am having trouble moving the access to Angularfire into a service module in Ionic.

Firebase Data:

```
/Teams:
    /1:
        Name: Team A
        City: Some Town
    /2:
        Name: Team B
        City: Another Town
```

When I use the new AngularFire2, RC5, I have changes for the new valueChanges() access and my page displays the information.

```
let Location:string = '/Teams;
let DataList:Observable<any>;
return DataList = this.AfDb.list(Location).valueChanges();
```

The output is then:

```
Team A from Some Town
Team B from Another Town
```

The problem with trying to move my data into a service, is I need to work with some of the data more generically, without knowing that this is a Team object.  I am stuck trying to use the `map()` function as I am having trouble mapping the data.  My first basic attempt is to bring the Key into the structure automatically (1, 2) into a Key field, but I cannot get the map to work.

```
let Location:string = '/Teams';
let DataList:Observable<any>;
let ReturnData:Array<Team> = new Array<Team>();

DataList = this.AfDb.list(Location).valueChanges().map( 
    (DataRecord) => ReturnData.push(new Team(DataRecord.$key, DataRecord.$value.Name, DataRecord.$value.City ));

return ReturnData;
```

I do not get compiler errors, but nothing is returned to my page, and if I try to output the results, nothing is returned.

Comment: use _`snapshotChanges()`_ as shown in my answer

Comment: @SurajRao unfortunately this question has been closed, so I cannot accept or see your answer.  The reference question that most people point to is simply to get the data though, as I am trying to work with it to return something different than the default Observable as I need to manipulate the data first. I need to loop through all the records returned, process them, and return something different from my service (Array Object)

Comment: It would be something like `this.AfDb.list(Location).snapshotChanges().map( 
    (DataRecord) => ReturnData.push(new Team(DataRecord.payload.key, DataRecord.payload.val().Name, DataRecord.payload.val().City ));`

Comment: @SurajRao Thanks, I was able to work through to that with your snapshotChanges data.  Wish I could accept the answer for you.